# How to handle 401/403 responses from server optimally on global level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, superagent

Currently, I'm using a helper function and an `if` condition which pushes the current location to `/login` whenever there's a 401(unauth) or 403(forbidden) response from the api, like this:

```
request.get(//api url here)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', token)
        .then(res => if (res.status_code === 401 || res.status_code === 403) {
           helper.redirectToLogin() // pushes the current page to login page
          } else
              dispatch({type: "FETCHED_DATA"}))
```

**The Question:**

I'm using this helper function to handle any 401/403 responses in all the action files(around 20 of them) which have multiple api calls. **So, is there a way to handle such responses globally so that I don't have to put the `if` condition and helper function in every api call, probably an api middleware or something of that sort?**

Comment: Is creating a function that calls this on your behalf an acceptable outcome?

Comment: Yes, as long as I don't have to put the conditional check and helper function calls in each api call or only at the global level.

Comment: As @Shadow suggested, you can create a wrapper for all required HTTP methods and reject the promise if the status is not 200 (or others as required). Then while using it use a catch block to redirect as required.

Comment: It'd be better if you can show some code, thanks.

Comment: @gnmani I too have the same concern. It would be helpful if you could give some code

Answer (score 0):

We have Axios Request and Response Interceptors. Check with the Response Interceptor docs. They have well defined.

https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors